# convert charfield to string django

Tags: python, django, string, templates, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a CharField to a string in Django 1.2.5

I have this in my template:

```
{% mp3_metadata audio.audiogalleryitem.link %}
```

and a custom template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def mp3_metadata(link):
    link = str(link)
    filename, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(link)
    tag = TinyTag.get(filename)
    return mark_safe(tag.title)
```

but the link is not working. However it works fine when I manually specify the link as follows:

```
link = u'https://ia902508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3'
```

How can I get this work with the variable passed from the template?

Comment: Have you tried without the `.link` on the end of `audiogalleryitem`?

Comment: @aaron-lelevier - I just tried that now, and it doesn't work

Comment: A CharField *is* a string. You should show the error you get, and the definition of Audio and AudioGallery.

Comment: Plus, you **absolutely must** upgrade your Django version. 1.2.5 is seven years old and completey unsupported.

Comment: @daniel-roseman - I don't see an error which makes it harder to debug. I have DEBUG = True in my settings file, but I think it is something to do with the way the templates are called from another app that I don't see the error. How can I get view the error / traceback in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it appeared to be a wav file in the mp3 playlist causing the error, it was just difficult to track down.